# How to convert/cast from a protocol to a class in swift?

Tags: ios, class, swift, protocols

Pretty simple, I'd have thought; I just want to check if a variable is a class and cast it to one if possible.

For example:

```
var cellProtocol:MyTableViewCellProtocol? = nil
cellProtocol = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
```

how do I explicitly cast the cell to a UITableViewCell?

Inheritance as follows:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MyTableViewCellProtocol {
//....
}


@objc protocol MyTableViewCellProtocol: class, NSObjectProtocol {
    func configureCell()
}
```

That protocol definition was the result of me trying to solve this problem. My original one didn't have the @`objc` tag in it or the `class`-only identifier.

I tried a few things to make the cast happen but it has not worked:

```
    var cellToReturn = cellProtocol as UITableViewCell
```

This doesn't compile because `UITableViewCell` does not inherit explicitly from `MyTableViewCellProtocol`.

```
    var cellToReturn = cellProtocol as AnyObject as UITableViewCell
```

This fails at runtime because `cellProtocol` fails to cast into `AnyObject`.

I haven't been able to get the `unsafeBitCast` thing to work yet but that's another possibility I've been exploring.

Just a note, that this DOES work in Obj-C.

```
id<MyTableViewCellProtocol> cellProtocol = cell;
[cellProtocol configureCell];
UITableViewCell *cellCast = (UITableViewCell *)cellProtocol;
```

This gives me no errors and runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3 Beta, this compiles:

```
var cellToReturn = cellProtocol as! UITableViewCell
```

As of Swift 1.1, You have to cast it to `AnyObject` or `Any`, then `UITableViewCell`. I think this was a kind of bug.

```
var cellToReturn = cellProtocol as AnyObject as UITableViewCell
```

---

ADDED: It turns out that it's a problem of `Optional`

In this case, `cellProtocol` is `MyTableViewCellProtocol?`. you have to unwrap it first, then cast.

Try:

```
var cellToReturn = cellProtocol! as AnyObject as UITableViewCell
//                             ^
```

Comment: My cell does inherit from UITableViewCell, I just messed up when transcribing, sorry about that!

Good to know that it works in swift 1.2!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only be a `MyTableViewCellProtocol`, you should use that in the `as` clause. If you want conditional casting, use a `if let`.

```
if let cellProtocol = <dequeue> as? MyTableViewCellProtocol {
  // You're an object that conforms to MyTableViewCellProtocol.
  if let mycell = cellProtocol as? MyTableViewCell {
    // You're a MyTableViewCell object
    if let cell = cell as? UITableViewCell {
      // You're a UITableViewCell object
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that you can only check protocol conformance on protocols specified as `@objc` (but you've already done that).

Comment: I guess that's one way to do things to just avoid the cast altogether. However, is there a way to do the actual cast?

Comment: Which cast would you like?

Comment: turning a var that's of type MyTableViewCellProtocol into a UITableViewCell

Comment: those as keywords need to be as? but even then, the second one does not compile. The exact error is Type 'UITableViewCell' does not conform to protocol MyTableViewCellProtocol. I guess I did a bad job conveying this in the question but that's what my whole question was about.